# Determine which rectangle on picturebox is clicked

Tags: c#

I have a c# WinForms project with a picture box that contains a document with text.  I am gathering the OCR data for the document using the Google Cloud Vision API, which works great.  Using the bounding rectangles returned from the Google API, I am drawing rectangles around each word using DrawRectangle, and in the process I am associating that rectangle with the underlying word.  What do I need to do to be able to just click on any given rectangle and know exactly which rectangle it is without having to take the point clicked and loop through all the coordinates of all the rectangles until I find it.

Comment: Hello,we're glad you approached us.We're here to help each other.But to help us help you,you need to explain your issue.You're halfway done by sharing the problem but adding some relevant code,providing debugging information is more than helpful for us.So,i suggest you to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: This is not an answer, just a link(before the flaming starts).  But you can take the position of your click, and try this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.contains(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ps, good luck Richard (he's a former co-worker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four options for ya OP

### Just loop

> Take the point clicked and loop through all the coordinates of all the rectangles until I find it

This is actually the simplest answer and possibly the best performing answer for a relatively small (<1000) rectangles. If your rectangles might overlap, be sure to store and loop through them in z-order from front to back.

### Assisted lookup

If you have a crap ton of rectangles, you could create an additional data structure to assist with lookups. For example, you could define a 10x10 array where each element contains a list of the rectangles that overlap a portion of the screen. That way you can narrow the search. Of course there is additional overhead of maintaining the list, so it may not be worth it, depending on your usage characteristics.

### Custom controls

As an alternative, you could change your approach completely and render each rectangle as its own [custom control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/developing-custom-windows-forms-controls). As a custom control, it will have a click event handler just like any Win32 window.  However there is considerable overhead in instantiating and managing all those controls, so this is not recommended for a large number of rectangles. Also, under the covers I'm pretty sure it'll end up using the same lookup algorithms described above, so it won't perform any better.

### Bindable class

A final option is to create a class specifically for the rectangle and "bind" it to the PictureBox (register as a consumer for its events). Then every rectangle will handle the click event and raise its own event if the click was within its boundaries. Here is an example to get you started:

```
class ClickableRectangle
{
    private Rectangle _box;

    public event EventHandler Click;

    public ClickableRectangle(Rectangle coordinates)
    {
        _box = coordinates;
    }

    public void BindToControl(Control control)
    {
        control.MouseUp += Control_MouseUp;
        control.Paint += Control_Paint;
    }

    private void Control_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, _box);
    }

    private void Control_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_box.Contains(e.X, e.Y)) return;
        if (Click != null) Click(this, e);
    }
}
```

Then to display a new rectange in `MyPictureBox`, and to handle them with a method called `MyClickHandler`, just call

```
var r = new ClickableRectangle(myRectangle);
r.BindToControl(MyPictureBox);
r.Click += this.MyClickHandler;
```

Voila.

See also [this related question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/what-are-the-algorithms-and-the-data-structures-for-guis-and-input-management).

Comment: It will never have a "crap ton" of rectangles.  The application could require a lot of back-to-back-to-back clicks, and was hoping to avoid the overhead of repeatedly having to loop through all the coordinates.  Come to think of it, though, Google breaks things down into Blocks and Paragraphs and Words.  I can probably use this to narrow down the scope of the search!  Woohoo!

Comment: I do not agree, just use a simple list of the rectangles and a linq where statement. it's like 3 lines of code

Comment: Edited with another option that avoids loops.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance!